# UINavigationController hide only navigationBar - Back animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have three viewControllers in a `UINavigationController`. In the second one I need to hide the navigation bar **but not the back button and other bar button**. For this reason I can't use `isNavigationBarHidden = true`
Currently I am handling the above as follows :

First viewController :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = Constants.kThemeRedColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }
```

Second viewController (hide only nav bar) :

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
```

The issue here is that when I navigate from and to the firstViewController, for a very short duration when the 1st viewController is disappearing and appearing respectively, I see a black nav bar on it. I know this is because of the code written in 2nd viewController. But I don't have any other close solution of doing this. Attaching a screenshot :

**First viewController (how it should be) :**

[image]

**Second viewController :**

[image]

**First viewController (with black nav bar for short duration) :**

[image]

Comment: what is your bacground view color? is tableview below navbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `First viewController`, also set the `backgroundImage` and `shadowImage` of `navigationBar` as `nil`, i.e.

```
class FirstVC: UIViewController
{
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nil, for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = nil
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .black
    }
}

class SecondVC: UIViewController
{
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)
        self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly fine. Thanks. I also need to ask that while going from VC1 to VC2, same thing happens. For a very short duration the nav bar of VC1 turns black while navigating to VC2. How can I fix that ?

Comment: Got that working too. Solution : 
In VC2, set :
self.navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = Constants.kThemeRedColor

Answer (score 0):

You should hide Navigation Controller's Navigation Bar and use custom navigation Bar using UIView. I think it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First viewController is showing with black nav bar for short duration on quick transition because of background color of UIWindow on which navigaion-bar transitions are happening. Simply, add this line in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method of AppDelegate

```
window?.backgroundColor = Constants.kThemeRedColor
```

And you are done. Happy coding!