# Transparent navigation bar glitch

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, transparency

I need to make the navigation bar in some view controllers transparent (but with the bar buttons visible).

I wrote the following extension for that.

```
extension UINavigationBar {
    func setTransparent(_ flag: Bool) {
        if flag == true {
            setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
            shadowImage = UIImage()
            backgroundColor = .clear
            isTranslucent = true
        } else {
            setBackgroundImage(nil, for: .default)
        }
    }
}
```

The default styles for my navigation bars are as follows.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 45/255, green: 93/255, blue: 131/255, alpha: 1)
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

All this works fine. But there's a problem if I have to turn off the transparent effect.

Say in the first view controller I don't need the navigation bar to be transparent.

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setTransparent(false)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    }
}
```

I push to the second view controller from here. In here, the navigation bar is transparent.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setTransparent(true)
    }

}
```

Now when I pop back to the previous view controller, I have to explicitly set the `isTranslucent` property to `false`. I do that in the `viewWillAppear` as you can see in the first code snippet.

But the problem is, the navigation bar is black for a second when it happens.

[image]

I want this to be smooth. How do I avoid this?

Demo project uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/urv6n48agzs9igs/TransparentNav.zip?dl=0).

---

I tried the solution described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604412/1077789) to a similar question. But it doesn't completely fix my issue. The black bar is gone but the navigation bar doesn't appear for a second just like before as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyHqX.jpg).

Comment: Check [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603451/uinavigationcontroller-hide-only-navigationbar-back-animation-issue). I have already faced this.

Comment: @Nitish Thanks. But unfortunately it doesn't completely fix it at least in my case. The black bar is gone. But still the navigation bar doesn't appear for a second there as you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/P1MXh).

Comment: @Isuru Do you resolve the last part of issue when navigation bar doesn't appear for a second?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Black navigation bar you see is actually a navigation controller view background color. Try add this code in first view controller `viewDidLoad` method

```
navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting the navigation controller view background color did fix the black issue for me, but I was still having the "delay" problem when popping a view controller.

I fixed it by changing the theme of my NavigationController on the willMove method of the view controller being popped. Something like this:

```
override func willMove(toParent parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.willMove(toParent: parent)
    guard parent == nil,
          let navController = self.navigationController else {
            return
    }

    navController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navController.view.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = barColor
    navController.navigationBar.tintColor = tintColor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before Push I use

```
     if let navigator = self.navigationController {
           navigator.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
           navigator.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.black]
           navigator.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
     }
```

this make the glitch disappear working fine...

note in my case background color was white