# Hide top- and toolbar on different view controllers in Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uinavigationbar

I'am working on an app, which is embedded in a `UINavigationController`. I like Storyboard, so I am looking for a solution that could be done in Storyboard. If that's not possible, I am doing it programmatically.

I want different settings for the top- and toolbar (hide/ show). See the image below.

[image: All <code>ViewControllers</code> have the same settings: topbar = "inferred"]

Now look at situation two. I want the third `ViewController` to have no topbar. But if I set it to "none", four and five have no topbar as well. See image:

[image: Third <code>ViewController</code> has settings: topbar = "none", rest "inferred".]

What I want is only the third controller not to have a topbar.

How is this possible in Storyboard?

Thanks!

Niels

Comment: This is somewhat related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46603451/uinavigationcontroller-hide-only-navigationbar-back-animation-issue

Answer (score 0):

In your `viewWillAppear()` of your third `ViewController` add this simple line of code -

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

**From Storyboard -**

Click on that specific ViewController where you don't want to show the bar then go to Attributes inspector. There is a drop down labeled Top Bar change this drop down to none

[image]

And for the smooth animation -

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // Hide the navigation bar on the this view controller
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Show the navigation bar on other view controllers
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I know how I can do it programmatically, but was hoping on a more elegant way in Storyboard. Moreover, the segue animation is not really nice/ smooth (even when animation is set to true).